# Replace control-characters with their ASCII-code in HEX

Tags: shell, replace

I'm parsing a file that may contain control-characters (ASCII 0-31). Now I want to replace each of those control-characters with their ASCII-code in hexadecimal representation. A rather simple example of what I have in mind:

```
$ echo -e "a\011b" | sed -e 's/\o11/\\x09/g'
a\x09b
```

This converts the tab (`\011`) to `\x09`, so the `a<tab>b` becomes `a\x09b`.

Obviously I could use 32 `-e`-parameters, but I consider that bad. Is there a generic approach to this?

BTW, it's not a problem if the `\n` remains a `\n`. `sed` isn't required.

Comment: Are octal escapes acceptable?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, the output must contain the `\x..` notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Perl.  Note that tab is actually 9, not 8 - if you're trying to change the value, then this is incorrect, but if you're just encoding, this should do the trick:

```
echo -e "a\011b" | perl -lpe 's/[\0-\037\177]/sprintf "\\x%02x", ord $&/ge'
```

Comment: lol, right. 011 obviously is 9. I fixed my question. But, maybe that's the key-reason why I want this to be generic ;)